Can we get the tag wiki (back) for [oracle-database] please?
As noted by marrados' answer to "Rename [oracle] to [oracle-database]", the oracle and oracle-database tags have been merged.
Unfortunately, this left us with the non-existant tag wiki that oracle-database had, instead of the informative tag wiki that oracle had.
Can we please get the old tag wiki from oracle back and applied to the new-ish oracle-database tag?

I think this should be the last revision of the excerpt and this of the wiki. I got these from copying the RevisionGUID in the results of this query I ran in SEDE. Feel free to edit that as the wiki / excerpt if it makes sense.

I pulled the last revision from the oracle tags and copied them over. Attribution is a bit grey now, but I put a link to the original revision in the edit comment which is I think the best I can do in this case.

Thanks @HenryEcker!
